# Unsupported media type error in android when trying to upload image

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an application which uploads an image to the server. I am getting a response, `415 unsupported media type` from the server. My code is as follows, what changes should I make?

```
class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... url){
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://10.155.103.167:9090/RestServer/rest/todos");

            String fileName = String.format("File_%d.png", new Date().getTime());
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, fileName);

            ContentBody mimePart = bab;

            // File file= new File("/mnt/sdcard/forest.png");
            // FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("file", bab);
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            int timeoutConnection = 60000;
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 60000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
            //txt.setText("NEW TEXT"+s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception here
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `postRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");` before your request is sent and please, LogCat.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot ,but now I am getting 500 internal error

Comment: As seen here: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm there are a lot of possible errors related to 500 internal, so Please paste the new LogCat etc.

Comment: Hi , I am not getting an any error in the log cat . what I have typed is the response I am getting from the server

Comment: As it was explained in the link I gave, you should take a look at what this error means for the concrete server, because it can be a lot of things. The good thing is that we got this moving and I suspect that the content-type is either not supported or unknown to the server. I'll see if I can find something more, you check with the server.

Comment: I found a solution for the mime types, it's here :http://james.apache.org/download.cgi#Apache_Mime4J - Include that into the build path of your project and see if it will recognize the type.

Comment: About the 500 error - see this http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html as well and also you should really check if the server supports these types of format. Try changing the Content-Type to `multipart/form-data` too.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced the same problem setting content type should solve the problem

```
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
```